Why is my BeautifulSoup script not parsing the .htm data correctly from the House of Commons' Register of Financial Interests page?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Contents page URL
url = "https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm/cmregmem/240930/contents.htm"

# Create a session
session = requests.Session()

# Set headers to mimic a Chrome browser on macOS
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm/cmregmem/240930/contents.htm',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
}

# Fetch the contents page
try:
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Find all links to MPs
        mp_links = soup.find_all('a')  # All anchor tags
        mp_data = []
        
        for link in mp_links:
            href = link.get('href')
            if href and 'cmregmem' in href:  # Filter for relevant MP links
                mp_name = link.text.strip()  # Get the MP's name
                mp_url = f"https://publications.parliament.uk{href}"  # Construct the full URL
                
                # Fetch each MP's page
                mp_response = session.get(mp_url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
                if mp_response.status_code == 200:
                    mp_soup = BeautifulSoup(mp_response.text, 'html.parser')
                    content = mp_soup.get_text()  # Get all text from the page
                    
                    # Look for the section containing shareholdings
                    if "Shareholdings" in content:
                        start_index = content.index("Shareholdings")
                        shareholdings_text = content[start_index:]  # Extract text from the start of the shareholdings section
                        mp_data.append((mp_name, shareholdings_text.strip().splitlines()))
                    else:
                        mp_data.append((mp_name, "No shareholdings found"))
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to retrieve data for {mp_name}, status code: {mp_response.status_code}")
                
                time.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second between requests to avoid overwhelming the server

        # Print the extracted data
        print("MP Name - Shareholdings")
        print("-" * 50)
        for mp in mp_data:
            print(f"{mp[0]} -")
            for line in mp[1]:
                print(f"  {line}")  # Print each line of the shareholdings
    else:
        print(f'Failed to retrieve data from the contents page, status code: {response.status_code}')

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

The above keeps giving me a 403 error. How can I make it spit out data contained on the shareholding section as a Python output? Open to any suggestions on improving any of the general code too, since it's my first scraper. I plan to use this to track political donations and investments.

why are you assuming it's in a table when it's not?

See updated code, assuming it's an anchor. 403 Error

you've completely changed the point of your question it's not making sense. revert your changes, the answer you received was a good one for your first question. it helped you. open a new question for the 403 problem

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_mp_data(base_url, contents_url):
    session = requests.Session()
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    }

    response = session.get(contents_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f'Failed to retrieve data, status code: {response.status_code}')
        return []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    mp_data = []

    links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'[a-z]+_[a-z]+\.htm'))
    
    for link in links:
        mp_name = link.text.strip()
        mp_url = f"{base_url}{link['href']}"
        
        mp_response = session.get(mp_url, headers=headers)
        if mp_response.status_code == 200:
            mp_soup = BeautifulSoup(mp_response.text, 'html.parser')
            shareholdings_section = mp_soup.find('h3', text='Shareholdings')
            holdings = []
            
            if shareholdings_section:
                next_sibling = shareholdings_section.find_next_sibling()
                while next_sibling and next_sibling.name in ['p', 'ul']:
                    if next_sibling.name == 'ul':
                        holdings.extend([li.text.strip() for li in next_sibling.find_all('li')])
                    elif next_sibling.name == 'p':
                        holdings.append(next_sibling.text.strip())
                    next_sibling = next_sibling.find_next_sibling()
            
            mp_data.append((mp_name, holdings))
        else:
            print(f'Failed to retrieve MP data for {mp_name}, status code: {mp_response.status_code}')
    
    return mp_data

def main():
    base_url = "https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm/cmregmem/240930/"
    contents_url = f"{base_url}contents.htm"
    
    mp_data = get_mp_data(base_url, contents_url)
    
    print("MP Name | Shareholdings")
    print("-" * 50)
    for mp_name, holdings in mp_data:
        holdings_str = ', '.join(holdings) if holdings else "No holdings found"
        print(f"{mp_name} | {holdings_str}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Hey, thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately, that code doesn't seem to work and gives me a 403 error code - any ideas on how to work around this?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
